# Combine CTE "WITH" and a "WITH XMLNAMESPACES...." in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Has anyone managed to create a CTE in SQL Server's T-SQL that also includes a `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` declaration?

It seems both `WITH` keywords insist on being the "first in the T-SQL batch", and that doesn't really work....

I tried:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.myself.com/SomeSchema' as ns)
WITH CTEQuery AS
(
SELECT (list of fields)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (conditions)
)
SELECT * FROM CTEQuery
```

Didn't work :-( (syntax errors)

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change
>   tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

So I tried prepending the second `WITH` with a semicolon:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.myself.com/SomeSchema' as ns)
;WITH CTEQuery AS
(
SELECT (list of fields)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (conditions)
)
SELECT * FROM CTEQuery
```

and got this:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

and then I tried putting the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` into the CTE:

```
WITH CTEQuery AS
(
   WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.myself.com/SomeSchema' as ns)
   SELECT (list of fields)
      FROM dbo.MyTable
      WHERE (conditions)
)
SELECT * FROM CTEQuery
```

and got this:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WITH'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change
>   tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

So how the heck do I do this??

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use a comma instead of the second `WITH`, e.g.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.myself.com/SomeSchema' as ns)
,CTEQuery AS
(
SELECT (list of fields)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (conditions)
)
SELECT * FROM CTEQuery
```

The same if you want multiple CTE expressions. You only need to specify `WITH` once, and then all other `WITH` blocks just use a comma instead of the keyword.

Comment: And `XMLNAMESPACES` must be defined first, before any `CTEs`.